# Java application making graphics card "squeal"

Tags: java, hardware

I have made as simple game in java, that only has a black background and one image. It runs at just over 2000 fps, but when I launch it I can hear a high pitched sound being emitted from my computer. I assume this is my graphics card.

Is this normal and can it damage my card or should I just not worry about it? If so, how can I prevent it from happening? I assume I would need to cap the fps at a certain amount.

Comment: What kind of monitor are you using (LCD or CRT)? Sometimes the magnets in CRTs can cause this on a high-contrast mostly black image, especially if the image is moving. In my experience, anyway. I don't think LCDs do this, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Is the frame-rate directly correlated to the pitch of the squeal?  If so, you should modify the program to play the theme to Battlestar Galactica, and win nerd points on YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd personally monitor your GPU temperature. If it exceeds any certain thresholds, then I'd be concerned. There are numerous tools to do this. http://www.gputemp.com/ is one of them.

Comment: agreed! lm-sensors on linux